# Calculate sum inside a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I am designing a neural network with Tensorflow. I have a tensor `G` with shape: `[batch_size, C, 1 + x + y, feature_size]`, I want to calculate the sum of `x` and `y` vectors inside `G`, so that the new `G` has shape: `[batch_size, C, 3, feature_size]`. So which operation in Tensorflow should I use?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, C, 1+x+y, feature_size))
s1 = inp[:, :, 0:1, :]
sx = tf.reduce_sum(inp[:, :, 1:x+1, :], axis=2, keepdims=True)
sy = tf.reduce_sum(inp[:, :, -y:, :], axis=2, keepdums=True)
result = tf.concat((s1, sx, sy), axis=2)
```